# Priority queue implementation in C

Tags: c

Is there any reliable and simple priority queue (linked list preferred, not necessary) implementation for C?

More generally, what C standard libraries do you use?

Comment: Why do you mean by "what standard libraries?"

Comment: I like to implement my PQs on top of binomial heaps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out [PQLib](http://www.ohloh.net/p/pqlib).

I use the standard C standard libraries. ;)

Comment: Please, please PLEASE read the LICENSE file in PQLib _very_ carefully. It re-introduces a whole new kind of advertising clause (even worse than the original BSD advertising clause) and is incompatible with the GPL/LGPL (all versions). Basically, you can't link againtst glibc and PQLib and distribute the final product legally. The library is most decidedly _not_ open source, much less free software.

Comment: @Tim I didn't realize... it says BSD, but they must mean special BSD.  +1

Comment: DO NOT USE PQLIB. It is not complete and does not work.

Answer (score 7):

**PQLib** (the current accepted answer) **is incomplete** and the functionality doesn't match the documentation as of this posting.  E.g., the pq_dequeue documentation says it returns an entry.  The implementation returns NULL.  There are many "TO DO" comments in the code, such as, "remove node containing highest priority entry from its heap."  Essential logic is missing.

To anyone looking for a priority queue: I recommend finding some code that has good, passing unit tests.  I don't recommend PQLib unless it's updated and includes tests.

To the owner of PQLib or anyone recommending it: I assumed this code was complete and spent a fair bit of time debugging until I realized it wasn't, which was frustrating.  Please don't recommend code you haven't tried or know to be a work in progress.

Comment: yeah just wasted an hour - should have read a bit more of this thread!

Answer (score 5):

The [source code](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/Algs3.c1-4/code.txt) accompanying [Robert Sedgewick](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/)'s [Algorithms in C, Parts 1-4 (Fundamental Algorithms, Data Structures, Sorting, Searching)](http://amzn.com/0201314525) contains both a heap-based and a list-based implementation.  See Chapter 9 - Priority Queues and Heapsort.

Answer (score 3):

I have a priority queue written in C, hosted on google code. MIT license

https://code.google.com/p/pqueue-heap-c/source/browse/trunk/pqueue.cpp

The code has been used in a few projects so it's solid, but I wrote it in '98 so I don't remember how to use it. Don't be misled by the cpp extension. It's straight C.

Comment: What projects have used your code? Thank you for making and sharing this!

Comment: You're welcome @Darakian I used this in some path finding code in a video game quite a long  time ago in the late 90's.

Comment: You can't share which game can you?

Comment: This code or at least a similar version of it was used in a Playstation game called Batman and Robin and I also used it in an A* algorithm implementation but it was never used as I later rewrote it in C++ and used STL's built in priority queue.