# Priority queue in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm looking for a priority queue in Racket that satisfies the following definition, especially the bit in bold (from Wikipedia):

> a priority queue is an abstract data type which is like a regular queue or stack data structure, but where additionally each element has a "priority" associated with it. In a priority queue, an element with high priority is served before an element with low priority. **If two elements have the same priority, they are served according to their order in the queue**.

What I understand (and indeed want) by this, is that they are served according to the order that they were added to the queue.

I've tried Racket's `data/heap` but this doesn't maintain the correct ordering if the priorities are the same.

Test code:

```
#lang racket

(require data/heap)

(define h (make-heap
           (λ (p1 p2)
             (<= (car p1) (car p2)))))

(define (add! p) (heap-add! h p))

(add! '(1 a))
(add! '(2 b))
(add! '(3 c))
(add! '(3 d))
(add! '(3 e))
(add! '(3 f))
(add! '(3 g))
(add! '(3 h))
(add! '(3 i))

(for ([p (in-heap h)])
     (display p))
```

Output:

```
(1 a)(2 b)(3 h)(3 g)(3 f)(3 e)(3 d)(3 c)(3 i)
```

I need the following output:

```
(1 a)(2 b)(3 c)(3 d)(3 e)(3 f)(3 g)(3 h)(3 i)
```

Comment: This seems to be the same problem in another language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909617/how-to-preserve-the-order-of-elements-of-the-same-priority-in-a-priority-queue-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard heap. Keep a counter i which is incremented for each insertion. To insert an element x into the priority queue insert (list i x) into the heap. Your order predicate can now break ties using i.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Code here: https://github.com/ericclack/racket-stamps/blob/z-order/private/priority-queue.rkt